# Memory doesn't seem to be released after re-requiring JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, garbage-collection

In a loop that I made, I delete and re-require a json file where the contents are arbitrary 5000 times (in my case it was just this:

```
{
  "hello": "trash",
  "thing": "there"
}
```

I log the memory usage before the loop, when the loop has finished, and after a forced garbage collection as such:

```
var util = require('util')
var trash = require('./trash.json')

console.log(`Original:\n${util.inspect(process.memoryUsage())}`)

for (let tries = 0; tries < 5000; tries++) {
  try {delete require.cache[require.resolve('./trash.json')]} catch (e) {}
  require('./trash.json');

  if (tries === 4999) console.log(`New:\n${util.inspect(process.memoryUsage())}`);
}

global.gc()
console.log(`After collection:\n${util.inspect(process.memoryUsage())}`)
```

The output was:

```
Original:
{ rss: 19767296,
  heapTotal: 7319552,
  heapUsed: 3262680,
  external: 8220 }
New:
{ rss: 32210944,
  heapTotal: 17805312,
  heapUsed: 10002312,
  external: 32796 }
After collection:
{ rss: 32989184,
  heapTotal: 26193920,
  heapUsed: 7442936,
  external: 32796 }
```

It seems that even after garbage collection `heapUsed` is still so much larger than the original. When I remove `require('./json')` however, `heapUsed` is much lower:

```
Original:
{ rss: 19718144,
  heapTotal: 7319552,
  heapUsed: 3262640,
  external: 8220 }
New:
{ rss: 24309760,
  heapTotal: 10465280,
  heapUsed: 5084248,
  external: 8220 }
After collection:
{ rss: 24436736,
  heapTotal: 10465280,
  heapUsed: 3542584,
  external: 8220 }
```

It seems from this that if you delete caches and re-require them numerous times throughout a Node process's lifetime, it is inevitable that it will eventually eat up the system's memory and garbage collection can't do anything about it.

But I am still learning how memory management works - is it possible (after numerous cache deletions and re-requires) to have the memory used return to near its original value?

What exactly is occupying memory even after garbage collection?

Comment: What real world thing are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: My program's application is where whenever there are any changes to a list of JSON files, it will delete the cache and re-require them so anything referencing them will not have outdated values. It follows the same logic as this, minus the looping of course. After some time however, my system drastically slows down and `free -h` shows 0 swap available and was wondering if the old cache actually gets released from memory with the garbage collector.

Comment: Maybe you should just load JSON files with `fs.readFile()` and `JSON.parse()`.  Then, nobody will be caching them in a way that you have to try to defeat.

Comment: It would appear that might be the only way to go since this is a persisting issue. Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to go away when I try it myself with a simple function that uses `fs.readFileSync()` and `JSON.parse()` instead of `require()`.  I don't know why.

Comment: FYI, you could likely examine a heap snapshot and figure out what is still occupying memory.  That can be a tedious job, but the info would probably be there.

Comment: Someone else just told me that modules loaded via `require` are never unloaded from memory - so it seems like it's just the way Node handles modules via `require` that's the problem (if it is, in fact, a problem and not intentional).